# Webpack missingmodule Cannot find module "scripts/build.js"

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have installed webpack as a dev dependency and set up the webpack.config.js.

The content of webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './scripts/test.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'scripts'),
        filename: 'build.js'
    }
};
```

For some reasons, it is throwing the following error

```
build.js:10431 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "scripts/build.js"
    at webpackMissingModule (build.js:10431)
    at Object.<anonymous> (build.js:10431)
    at __webpack_require__ (build.js:10372)
    at build.js:10415
    at Object.<anonymous> (build.js:10418)
    at __webpack_require__ (build.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (build.js:86)
    at __webpack_require__ (build.js:20)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (build.js:63)
    at build.js:66
```

Can I know what is the problem?

The content of test.js file is

```
console.log("testing");
```

The command which I have used;

```
./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ./scripts/test.js ./scripts/build.js
```

Comment: May you please provide the command you are using to run your config file?

Comment: I would recommend you keep your source and build directories separate. So you do not accidentally import a script produced as an output of the build. Can you post the contents of `test.js`?

Comment: @fshock Add the command which I have used.

Comment: @JoshuaBarnett Added the content of the test.js file.

Comment: What is inside `build.js`? Is it the webpack config file?

Comment: @fshock build.js is the file where webpack emits the content.

Comment: I don't think so. I think that webpack considers the second file as the second input (entry point), that is. What do you think?

Also, if you have a `webpack.config.js`, I do not see the use of running the webpack command and supplying the entry points manually. Running just `webpack` should suffice, since it will automatically look for the `webpack.config.js` file and bundle the files specified from the entry point and output to the output you specified in the config file.